# delete an specific embedded object in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

Here is my java program:

```
try {
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("SchoolProject");
    boolean auth = db.authenticate("root", "root@123".toCharArray());
    System.out.println(auth);

    if(auth==true){
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("Bus_route");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("BusId", "BUS_101");
        BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
        data.put("Route.$.stop_name", "hyderabad");
        data.put("Route.$.arrival_time", "1:05");
        BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
        command.put("$unset", data);

        table.update(query, command);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

and mongodb document:

```
"BusId" : "BUS_101",
"DriverName" : "Alex",
"Route" : [
    {
        "stop_name" : "st. John Road",
        "arrival_time" : "10:30"
    },
    {
        "stop_name" : "hyderabad",
        "arrival_time" : "1:05"
    }
],
"SchoolName" : "St. John Paul",
"VehicleNo" : "A20y6757",
"_id" : ObjectId("529f093cdaa62b1b10b82cc1")
```

and
document name: Bus_route

delete an specific embedded object in mongodb
how to delete object named hyderabad in an array Route with out removing others?

after I got help from this forum I got it, below is the code

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("Bus_route");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("BusId", "BUS_101");

BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
data.put("stop_name", "hyderabad");

BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
command.put("$pull", new BasicDBObject("Route", data));

table.update(query,  command);
```

Comment: You have to do an update using the $pull operator (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: I have used $pull projection instead of $unset but i got error as,

Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

Comment: db.Bus_route.update({ BusId: "BUS_101" },{$pull:{'Route':{'stop_name':'hyderabad'}}})